# NLP on compiler output and other system error messages

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim

Hello stack overflow community,

I have the following problem: I am currently mining a database of support tickets and would like to use e.g. Doc2Vec to check for similarities between tickets. However, the text contains huge strings, produced by the OS or compiler commands. So it would not be clever to use those strings as single words in the model. What is a good practice here? Does have anyone experience with something like that?

Best
Thorsten

Comment: If you have enough data you can use any vector space model to learn the word vectors/embeddings, which you can then use for the task at hand. Embedding/vector of your ticket could be either addition or multiplication of your individual vectors of strings/words in a ticket.

Comment: Hi Riyaz, thanks for your reply. However, the problem is that it will learn long directory names as a single word since they contain no whitespaces. If another user filed a bug report about the same thing, but since he uses another directory structure that output will contain a different set of words.as As far as I know, doc2vec treats words as atomic quantities, and does not do substring matching. For natural text, people use stemming to preprocess the data, which gets rid of a lot of these issues. So what I need here I think is dome kind if stemming which can deal with compiler/OS output.